# Lazy loading angular app doesn't load a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I'm trying to lazy load a directive in my angular app, using ui.router and oc.lazyLoad. Here is my code :

menu :

```
<ul>
      <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="demo">Demo</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="test">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
```

route config :

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state("demo", {
            url:'/demo',
            views: {
              'lazyLoadView' : {
                template: '<demo-directive></demo-directive>'
              }
            },
            resolve : {
              loadDemoModule : ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                console.log('resolving demo lazy load');
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('demo.js');
              }]
            }
          })
          .state("home", {
            templateUrl : 'core/home.html',
            url : '/home'
          })
}])
```

and the directive :

```
angular.module('app').
directive('demoDirective', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: require('./demo-directive.html'),
    // templateUrl: 'demo-directive.html', 
    controllerAs: 'demo',
    controller : ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
      console.log('in directive controller');
    }]
  };

});
```

I have no errors, the `console.log` in resolve function is displayed, the demo.js file is loaded but then noting is happening, console form directive controller is not displayed. I'm trying to follow the first example from [ocLazyLoad example](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about lazy loading this way.

```
return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'app.demo',
                        files: ['path/to/demo.js']
                    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately my directive is still not loaded.

Comment: since you app module and directive module name is different, isn't it necessary to inject your directive module name to main module

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the oc.lazyLoad module as a dependency.

```
angular.module('app.demo', ["oc.lazyLoad"])
```

See the quickstart - https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/

You're also not closing your demo directive

```
 template: '<demo-directive></demo-directive>'
```

Comment: I updated my code, my route config is attached to another module which includes the oclazyload dependency. I updated my post. I also added closing tag for directive, but still the same problem.

Comment: You're declaring two seperate modules. App and App.Demo, you need to connect them, add app.demo as a dependency for app.
Just as an example, have a look at the modules section of this style guide by jon papa. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules

Another alternative is to keep them in the same module, so you would change this "angular.module('app.demo', [])" to "angular.module('app') "

Comment: thanks, I didn't see this. I updated my code with "angular.module('app') " but still no luck.